# How to configure checkstyle magic number rule so that ignore some packages?

Tags: swing, sonarqube, checkstyle

I use sonar, I want to know how can i configure only checkstyle magic number rule so that it ignores some package that contain `Swing` related class.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [Sonar Switch Off Violation Plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Switch+Off+Violations+Plugin) to do so.